# Is there a service that allows you to upload and download files (download programatically)?

Tags: java, hosting

I am making a sample app. And I want to download a small text file when the app opens. I need a host where I can upload this file and keep. I need a host which will provide me a with a downloadable link for the file, so that I can download the file from my java program.
 Is there any such service provided my anyone? I do not need it for long term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try 
http://pastebin.com/

There you can paste chunks of text and then download them from the php script provided in the same page (the download button)